# What is the design pattern to use for extending a base class with additional properties?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have "business entities" and their counterpart for saving them to Azure Storage Table, which requires a few additional properties.

```
// MyData is the business entity with a few properties
public record MyData_AzureTable : MyData, ITableEntity
{
    // Required properties for storing data to Azure Storage Table
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; } = "";
    public string RowKey { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; } = new ETag();
}
```

I am getting tired of having to duplicate each business entity with its AzureTable counterpart but I can't find the correct pattern to use. Something like that, except it's illegal to inherit from a type parameter.

```
public record AzureTable<T> : T, ITableEntity
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; } = "";
    public string RowKey { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; } = new ETag();
}
```

What pattern should be used for adding properties to a base class?

The object saved to Azure Table Storage needs to be "flat" (tabular data as property values, no hierarchical data or encapsulation)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a *pattern* but abstract classes may fit well for your need here. Check out the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

In conclusion, those classes have a base one (which would be your always default AZ properties) and all the other classes than inherit from the abstract one will contain those properties as well without needing implementation (like an interface would) but you can extend the children and add more custom properties to each one.

Comment: Thanks! I don't want the business entities to expose the AzureTable properties, so the business entities cannot inherit a base class containing the AzureTable properties...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such pattern, currently C# does not support something like traits (though in some cases similar can be achieved with default interface member implementations) and/or multiple inheritance (basically `MyData_AzureTable` should inherit from both `MyData` and `AzureTable`). If you are really tired of writing "duplicates" for data - you should consider using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) -  you can write quite a simple one which will generate azure tables classes for all required classes (for example marked with special attribute like `GenerateAzureTable`). Potentially it can generate also some useful methods for mapping, copy constructors and so on.